# Visual Studio for Mac won't start after updating to version 7.5.3 - Assemblies not properly installed in the GAC

Tags: mono, visual-studio-2017

I updated Visual studio for mac from beta channel to latest stable channel and now it does't start anymore.
I reinstalled it and still doesn't start.

Here is a portion of the logs:

```
INFO [2018-07-04 00:16:23Z]: Starting Visual Studio 2017 for Mac 7.5.3 (build 7)
INFO [2018-07-04 00:16:23Z]: Running on Mono 5.10.1.57 (2017-12/ea8a24b1bbf) (64-bit)
INFO [2018-07-04 00:16:23Z]: Operating System: Mac OS X 10.13.5
Darwin 17.6.0 Darwin Kernel Version 17.6.0
    Tue May  8 15:22:16 PDT 2018
    root:xnu-4570.61.1~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
INFO [2018-07-04 00:16:23Z]: GTK: Using gtkrc from /Applications/Visual Studio.app/Contents/Resources/lib/monodevelop/bin/gtkrc.mac
Could not find `Microsoft.Build.Framework` referenced by assembly `MonoDevelop.Core, Version=2.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3ead7498f347467b`.
...
Starting Visual Studio
FATAL ERROR [2018-07-04 00:16:30Z]: Visual Studio failed to start. Some of the assemblies required to run Visual Studio (for example gtk-sharp)may not be properly installed in the GAC.
System.InvalidOperationException: Extension node not found in path: /MonoDevelop/Core/PlatformService
  at Mono.Addins.ExtensionContext.GetExtensionObjects (System.String path, System.Type arrayElementType, System.Boolean reuseCachedInstance) [0x0001c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5965/13cecd02/source/monodevelop/main/external/mono-addins/Mono.Addins/Mono.Addins/ExtensionContext.cs:670 
  at Mono.Addins.ExtensionContext.GetExtensionObjects (System.String path) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5965/13cecd02/source/monodevelop/main/external/mono-addins/Mono.Addins/Mono.Addins/ExtensionContext.cs:534 
  at Mono.Addins.AddinManager.GetExtensionObjects (System.String path) [0x0000a] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5965/13cecd02/source/monodevelop/main/external/mono-addins/Mono.Addins/Mono.Addins/AddinManager.cs:554 
  at MonoDevelop.Ide.DesktopService.Initialize () [0x00008] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5965/13cecd02/source/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Ide/MonoDevelop.Ide/DesktopService.cs:57 
  at MonoDevelop.Ide.IdeStartup.Run (MonoDevelop.Ide.MonoDevelopOptions options) [0x0030b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5965/13cecd02/source/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Ide/MonoDevelop.Ide/IdeStartup.cs:178 
  at MonoDevelop.Ide.IdeStartup.Main (System.String[] args, MonoDevelop.Ide.Extensions.IdeCustomizer customizer) [0x0008f] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5965/13cecd02/source/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Ide/MonoDevelop.Ide/IdeStartup.cs:627
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems I encountered a [known issue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releasenotes/vs2017-mac-preview-relnotes#--known-issues). A workaround is described [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/252901/visual-studio-2017-for-mac-75-build-1255-crashes-w.html) and it worked for me. It says to delete that folder: `~/Library/Caches/VisualStudio/7.0/addin-db-002/`